# раздумывать versus подумывать

Tags: выбор-слова, глаголы

I have seen both **раздумывать** and **подумывать** used in situations where the subject is giving serious thought to doing something. Thus in the sentence: **Я подумываю сказать пару слов после ужина**, the speaker is entertaining the possibility of addressing his guests. Could he just as well have used **раздумываю**? Are there any nuances that differentiate the choice of one over the other.

Interestingly enough, I saw the sentence: **Я уже подумываю позвонить твоему отцу!** which I interepreted as a threat or warning along the lines of *I have half a mind to call your father! (and tell him what you did)*. Would **раздумываю** here preserve the same tenor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Разд’умать**, -аю, -аешь; соверш. вид, с неопред.

1.Отказаться от задуманного, перерешить. --*to change one's mind,decision*.

> Раздумать ехать.(to change one's mind and not to go.)

несовершенный вид **раздумывать**, -аю, -аешь.

2. Думать, долго не приходя к какому-нибудь заключению, к решению. --*to think for a long time not coming to any decision, conclusion*.

> Раздумывать о случившемся.( to think of what happened )
>   Хватит раздумывать, соглашайся.(Stop thinking it over.Accept it.).

**Под’умывать**, -аю, -аешь; несовершенный вид (разговорн.).(colloquial )
1. От времени до времени думать о чём-нибудь предстоящем. --*from time to time to think about future events*

> Подумывать об отъезде.(to think about leaving ).

2. Намереваться сделать что-нибудь .--*to have an intention, to decide to do something*.

> Давно подумывал уехать.(I have been thinking about going away for a long time).

Back to your examples.

> Я **подумываю** сказать пару слов после ужина.-- I am thinking(I am determined, I know what to say) of saying something after dinner. The structure is *verb+infinitive*.

You can't just change the verb here, but you can say:

> Я **раздумываю**, сказать ли об этом после ужина.(или нет)(I am thinking whether to say about that after dinner or not. I haven't decided yet.)The structure is *verb+if clause(conditional )*.
>
> Я уже **подумываю** позвонить твоему отцу.(I am almost ready to call your father) *verb+infinitive*

You can't just change the verb here. But you can say, using *conditional*,

> Я **раздумываю**, позвонить  твоему отцу или нет.(I am thinking of calling but I haven't made up my mind yet).

Comment: So would it be more accurate to translate my sentence as "I mean to say a few words after dinner." (in the sense of "I intend to...")?

Comment: Sure, you made up your mind

Comment: I guess the thing that's confusing me is that making up one's mind is such a definitive and "perfective" act, and yet подумывал is imperfective. I'm having a hard time reconciling the form with the result.

Comment: To be on the point of... perhaps, but he is ready to say

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день!

В данном случае "раздумывать" означает процесс ( Пример: "Я раздумываю над проблемой потепления климата" - "I'm (trying to decide/ thinking of a) a problem of a global warming" ).

"Раздумать" - означает отказ от намерения ( Пример: "Я раздумал готовить ужин сегодня вечером" - "I decided not to cook dinner tonight" )

"Подумывать" - думать о чем-либо, имея альтернативу ( Пример: "Я подумываю завтра поехать за город" ( т.е. "Я еще не решил поеду я или нет" ) - "I still thinking about going to the village tomorrow, but I haven't made concrete decision yet - maybe I will, maybe I won't")

Comment: Спасибо Игорь! Я все понял, только интересно, как кому-ниубдь решить проблему потепления климата?

Comment: мне самомy интересно ;-) Имеется в виду какая-либо крупная проблема

Comment: So is there such a think as Я подумываю об этом and what would it imply?

Comment: @CocoPop: yes, and it implies thinking of/inclination to do something or make a decision. You cannot say подумывать about something like global warming or something happened in the past.

Answer (score 1):

«раздумываю» is more about the process, while «подумываю» is more about an intent.

Another difference is purely grammatical: they govern different prepositions/cases. In «раздумываю *о чем-либо*» the object is in the prepositional case, while in «подумываю *что-либо*» it's accusative.

«Я уже подумываю позвонить твоему отцу!» sentence could be used with «раздумываю», but in this case, a native speaker would likely use an indirect negation (sic!) «Я раздумываю, *не позвонить ли* мне твоему отцу!». I would say, the latter is the consequence of «раздумываю» being more about a process.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus in the sentence: Я подумываю сказать пару слов после ужина, the speaker is entertaining the possibility of addressing his guests. Could he just as well have used раздумываю?

"*Раздумываю*" means an alternative here. So you may say something like: "Я раздумываю сказать пару слов после ужина или нет".

> Would раздумываю here preserve the same tenor?

No, unless you mean colloquial "раздумываю" = "собираюсь передумать" = "I'm going to change my mind".

Normally "раздумывать" makes sense only as "fair thinking", so it's a "bad" threat. Of course one may make his intention more obvious, sort of: "Я уже раздумываю, не лучше ли в таком случае позвонить твоему отцу" etc. But as is the single verb "раздумывать" is too weak for that.

Comment: «раздумываю» = «собираюсь передумать» is an example of very rare usage, I would say, nearly impossible. The perfect form «раздумал» is identically equal to «передумал», though.

Comment: @mudasobwa Both colloquial and a little "bad", but I'd say it's not so rare.

Comment: I hardly could imagine «раздумываю» to be used in e. g. «я сейчас как раз раздумываю пойти в бар» (in the meaning “I am taking a decision to not go to the bar”.)